Añadir numero en listado de users, post o lo que corresponda con Laravel
Como añadir el número de fila a una consulta @forech, que por ejemplo muestre el listado de usuarios en Laravel.

El formato del sitio es de preguntas y respuestas. Y tú puedes responder a tu propia pregunta! Entonces, te invito a separar tu publicación en 2 y te recomiendo agregar una explicación con más detalles

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Expongo mi solución por si alguien tiene una mejor o le pueda servir a alguien.
Inicio del *.blade.php

cambiar $users por lo que corresponda

    @props([
    'i' => (request()->page > 1 )? (($users->perPage( ) * (request()->page -1))) + 1 :  1,
    ])

Donde corresponda poner el número:
{{ $i++ }}


No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.
